# does keccak256 and sha3 reproduce the same hash ?

Tags: sha3, keccak

I have this solidity method:

```
function hashData(bytes32 data) public constant returns (bytes32) {
    var hash = keccak256(data, msg.sender);
    return hash;
  }
```

for a **data =** "0x707974686f6e62" and **address =** "0x4c5f885b9854ce17e5620098e53f3032be002fed"

I dont get the same result using  `web3.sha3(data,address)`

Answer (score 3):

In *Solidity*, `sha3` and `keccak256` are aliases, so their output will be identical.

`web3.sha3` is a different function in a different programming language (I assume JavaScript). You would probably find [`web3.utils.soliditySha3`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3) helpful 
because as it reproduces the packing that Solidity does.

[ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) has a similar function in case you're not using web3.js 1.0.

Comment: I don't get why sha3 is alias for keccak256, being sha3-256 a different hash ... At least, yielding different results on https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html and https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_256.html

Comment: That's why they renamed to keccak256. As I recall, at the time Ethereum was developed, sha3 had not yet been finalized, and it was then equivalent to keccak256. In the latest version of Solidity, sha3 had been removed in favor of keccak256.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use web3 1.0 and `web3.utils.soliditySha3` to execute the sha3/keccak256 in the same way that Solidity would.

> Will calculate the sha3 of given input parameters in the same way
>   solidity would. This means arguments will be ABI converted and tightly
>   packed before being hashed.

[more info](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3)

Comment: I need a solution for web3 0.20

Comment: there's not unless you use web3.sha3(hash, {encoding: 'hex'}); but web3.sha3 takes only one argument  https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/lib/utils/sha3.js#L26 https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#example-10